# How to implement lazy loading using Spring data JPA (JPARepository)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate as a provider. I've created several Repository classes which extends to `JPARepository<Entity,Serializable>` class. I am failing at the moment when I am fetching one entity it brings attached / connected entities along with it ! which are either connected via `@OneToOne` `@OneToMany` etc. **How can I avoid fetching those connected entities ?**
I have tried with `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` etc but still no luck. Following are my java code:
**Repository**

```
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer>{

}
```

**Ticket Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_tickets")
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "customer", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String customer;


    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private User creator; 

    // ... other properties
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class TicketService {

  public Ticket save(Ticket obj,String id) {
       User user = userService.findById(Integer.valueOf(id));
       obj.setCreator(user);
       Ticket savedTicket = ticketRepository.save(obj);
   }
}
```

`savedTicket` always fetches User entity as well which I do not want to. How could I achieve this ?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your code is fetching an user object and setting "creator" on ticket and you expect creator to be null??

Comment: @RC. you are right, because of mapping I have to set it like that ! may be the way I mapped is wrong ! any idea on mapping part ?

Comment: there are problems with lazy fetching of OneToOne (perhaps solved in the answer of Harshal Patil below), however you should have no problems with lazy fetching of OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY). If the field gets initialized with such annotation, this might mean you access the property annotated with @OneToMany (which should be a set or a list etc.) somewhere before that.

Answer (score 1):

Get Lazy loading working on nullable one-to-one mapping you need to let hibernate do [Compile time instrumentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) and add a `@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)` to the one-to-one relation.

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn
@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private User creator;
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply, I added changes suggested by you, but it says `could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: @agpt  Add Transactional annotation over method where your are retrieving creator.